# Which axis to use to normalise 3 dimensional data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to know which axis is better to use for normalisation for a 3 dimensional data (it is the last axis by default). For example, I have this tensor with the shape `3 x 4 x 5` (`batch_size x number_of_elements x number_of_features`). Should I use axis 1 in this case so that I normalise each feature or the default axis -1 (2)?:

```
data = tf.constant(np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape(3, 4, 5) * 10, dtype=tf.float32)
print(data)

tf.Tensor(
[[[  0.  10.  20.  30.  40.]
  [ 50.  60.  70.  80.  90.]
  [100. 110. 120. 130. 140.]
  [150. 160. 170. 180. 190.]]

 [[200. 210. 220. 230. 240.]
  [250. 260. 270. 280. 290.]
  [300. 310. 320. 330. 340.]
  [350. 360. 370. 380. 390.]]

 [[400. 410. 420. 430. 440.]
  [450. 460. 470. 480. 490.]
  [500. 510. 520. 530. 540.]
  [550. 560. 570. 580. 590.]]], shape=(3, 4, 5), dtype=float32)

layer = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=1)
output = layer(data)
print(output)


tf.Tensor(
[[[-1.3416405  -1.3416405  -1.3416406  -1.3416405  -1.3416405 ]
  [-0.44721347 -0.44721353 -0.44721353 -0.44721353 -0.4472134 ]
  [ 0.44721353  0.44721353  0.4472134   0.44721353  0.44721365]
  [ 1.3416405   1.3416405   1.3416405   1.3416406   1.3416407 ]]

 [[-1.3416407  -1.3416407  -1.3416407  -1.3416405  -1.3416405 ]
  [-0.44721365 -0.44721365 -0.44721365 -0.44721317 -0.44721317]
  [ 0.44721317  0.44721317  0.44721317  0.44721365  0.44721365]
  [ 1.3416405   1.3416405   1.3416405   1.341641    1.3416405 ]]

 [[-1.341641   -1.341641   -1.341641   -1.341641   -1.34164   ]
  [-0.44721413 -0.44721413 -0.44721413 -0.44721413 -0.44721317]
  [ 0.44721317  0.44721317  0.44721317  0.44721317  0.44721413]
  [ 1.3416405   1.3416405   1.3416405   1.3416405   1.3416414 ]]], shape=(3, 4, 5), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Layer Normalization is performed across feature axis/axes. I am not sure what your axis=1 is, but, since you have multidimensional data, I assume this is a (spatial?) feature. So in your case you should use the option to pass a list to the function

```
tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=[1, 2])
```

some background can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-spatial-batch-instance-layer-normalization-in-tensorflow-manual-back-prop-in-tf-77faa8d2c362) where it says:

> [...] Assuming we have 4D tensor that represents (B,H,W,C), which
> stands for Batch, Height, Width, and Channel of image.

> **Batch Norm** → Take mean and variance respect to channel (1,1,1,c)

> **Layer Norm** → Take mean and variance respect to batch (b,1,1,1)

> **Instance Norm** → Take mean and variance respect to batch/channel (b,1,1,c)

Comment: This normalises all values in the batch, e.g. you get a single mean and deviation for all values. Why is this the correct way and `not axis=1` where we get the mean and the deviation for each feature?

Comment: imho that is the nature of layer normalization, you dont get mean and dev for each feature. I added a "source" to my answer,